# SQL Fail/not generating, when COUNT value equal to zero

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to generate a list for people view the available & cancelled class, somehow my SQL only print the class only people that reserved, the class people never reserve it never shows.

I suspect it because of **HAVING** that cause only generate reserved class.

My Table:

**Classes**

CID,
ClassLevel,
StartDate,
StartTime,
Duration,
Descp,
Status,
TID

[image]
**ClassReservation**:

ReservationID,
MID,
CID,
Status

[image]

When generate only display that people reserved class, but the class was create that people haven't reserve won't appear.

[image]

```
SELECT Classes.CID
    ,'Date: ' & Classes.StartDate & ', Start Time: ' & Classes.StartTime & ', Duration: ' & Classes.Duration & ', Description: ' & Classes.Descp & ', Status:  ' & Classes.STATUS AS CCOM
FROM Classes
INNER JOIN ClassesReservation ON Classes.CID = ClassesReservation.CID
WHERE (
        Classes.STATUS = 'active'
        OR Classes.STATUS = 'cancelled'
        )
    AND Classes.StartDATE > NOW
GROUP BY Classes.CID
    ,Classes.StartDate
    ,Classes.StartTime
    ,Classes.Duration
    ,Classes.Descp
    ,Classes.STATUS
HAVING COUNT(ClassesReservation.CID) < 20
    OR COUNT(ClassesReservation.CID) > 0
```

Comment: can u describe sample table data here

Comment: `>0 or <20` all numbers satisfy this condition. I think you want an `and`

Comment: Try using `left join`

Comment: @TedoG. tried left join, but the output still showing that class have more than 20people reserved

Comment: as @pinkfloydx33 commented, your `HAVING` clause causes it. You need  `AND` instead of `or`, as it does not filter any single record now.

Comment: tried both way no clue why it still only shows that class people reserve before, and the class was new created without reserve won't appear

Answer (score 0):

I would write the query like this:

```
SELECT c.CID,
       ('Date: ' & c.StartDate & ', Start Time: ' & c.StartTime & ', Duration: ' & Classes.Duration & ', Description: ' & c.Descp & ', Status:  ' & c.STATUS
       ) AS CCOM
FROM Classes as c INNER JOIN
     (SELECT cr.CID, COUNT(*) as NumReserved
      FROM ClassesReservation as cr
      GROUP BY cr.CID
     ) cr
     ON c.CID = cr.CID
WHERE c.STATUS IN ('active', 'cancelled') AND
      c.StartDATE > NOW
HAVING cr.NumReserved > 0 AND cr.NumReserved < 20;
```

Notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- `IN` is much more readable than a bunch of `=` clauses connect by `OR`.
- Moving the aggregation into a subquery simplifies the query.
- Your real problem is probably just the `OR` in the `HAVING` clause.